# SQL programming to remove dublictes

Tags: t-sql

I have issue with datediff function in sql stored procedure. because of the tiny seconds difference i am getting duplicate records in the database. If I changes datediff to other column filter I am having issue with front end application i. e. whhile user checking radio buttons not saving or not deleting for unchecked radio buttons. How can I solve this issue without datediff function

```
      DELETE FROM BSTankComp
      WHERE TankInspID=@TankInspID 
      and TankInspItem = @TankInspItem 
      AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, LastModified, GETDATE()) > .001

      --add new ones
      Insert into BSTankComp (TankInspID,TankInspItem,TankInspStat,TankCompDate,TankCompStat,ModifiedBy,
      LastModified) 
            values (@TankInspID, @TankInspItem, @TankInspStat, @TankCompDate, @TankCompStat, @UserID, GetDate())
```

Comment: Hello. Is this SQL Server or truly generic SQL. If SQL Server, you will want to tag it as such to get better responses.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Aside: [`DateDiff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-type) returns an `int`, so comparing it to `0.001` is a bit peculiar. And the value represents the number of _boundary crossings_.

Comment: What can I use instead of datediff function here so that i can remove duplicates beacuse of the small time difference.

Comment: Perhaps a closer reading of `DateDiff` [arguments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) would help. `millisecond`, `microsecond` and `nanosecond` date parts might be more useful. Note that they may also be mythical, e.g. [`datetime` precision](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision) is about 3ms, so checking for a difference of a single 100ns [clunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS#Timekeeping) won't work well.